# Context: How to place a table always at the bottom of a page?

Tags: context, extreme-tables

I would like to have a table that is always at the bottom of the first page.  There is not a lot of text before the table and afterwards should always start a new page.

MWE:

```
\starttext
\input knuth

 \placefloat[bottom][none]{}{
  \startxtable[option={stretch,width}]
    \startxrow
        \startxcell     Version:    \stopxcell
        \startxcell     1.0         \stopxcell
    \stopxrow
  \stopxtable}
\page
\input knuth
\stoptext
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! :: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you want to show only a short text the easiest solution is to put the text in the footer of the document. You can use the `\doif` commands to add the text only on the first page.

```
\setuppapersize [A5]

\startsetups [footerline]
    \simplealignedbox{.6\textwidth}{flushleft}{Version:}
    \simplealignedbox{.4\textwidth}{flushleft}{1.0}
\stopsetups

\setupfootertexts [\doif{\rawcountervalue[realpage]}{1}{\directsetup{footerline}}]

\starttext
\dorecurse{8}{\samplefile{knuth}}
\stoptext
```

[image: Limit footer text to the first page of the document]

**Edit**

When you have a title page you can use a `makeup` environment (`standardmakeup` or `textmakeup`) where you can move the table to the bottom of the page by adding `\vfill` before the table.

```
\setuppapersize [A5]

\starttext

\starttextmakeup[pagestate=start]

\samplefile{knuth}

\vfill

\startxtable[frame=off]
    \startxrow
        \startxcell[width=.6\textwidth]
            Version:
        \stopxcell
        \startxcell[width=.4\textwidth]
            1.0
        \stopxcell
    \stopxrow
\stopxtable

\stoptextmakeup

\samplefile{knuth}

\stoptext
```

[image: Title page with a table at the bottom]

Comment: The table I want to insert is bigger. The first page is the titlepage of the document. The table has six rows and contains information about the document (author, date, number of pages).

Comment: For title pages, another option is to use [Layers](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Layers) which gives you complete control of where the content should appear.

Answer (score 0):

Placing a `\vfill` just above the table and a `\clearpage` after it seems to work very well. Note this is a LaTeX answer, not specifically a ConTeXt one.

```
\clearpage
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{mybib}{}

\vfill 
{
\begin{table}[ht]
\caption{Change History} % title of Table
%\centering % used for centering table
\begin{tabular}{|| l | l | l | p{8cm} ||} \hline
 \textbf{Name} & \textbf{Revision} & \textbf{Date} & \textbf{Comments} \\ \hline \hline
 RPC & PA1 & 18SEP2018 & First Draft \\ \hline
 RPC & PA2 & 19SEP2018 & Proof reading corrections  \\ \hline
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
}
\clearpage

Last Page.

typeset in {\Huge \LaTeX} \today.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Note that the question is about ConTeXt and not LaTeX. It is okay to give a LaTeX solution, but you should at least point out that you are showing how to achieve the same in LaTeX and if there is some advantage/simplicity of the LaTeX solution.

Comment: OK. edited it. I found it very useful to know this technique and use it in my TeX docs at work now. Part of looking through these forums is that you learn stuff.